# ADMA5069E: The installation of application failed WebSphere

Tags: websphere

I tried to do an update installation using Websphere. I used ivtApp.ear just to test.

It throws the following exception:

```
ADMA5017I: Uninstallation of ivtApp started.

ADMA5104I: The server index entry for WebSphere:cell=localhostNode01Cell,node=localhostNode01 is updated successfully.

ADMA5102I: The configuration data for ivtApp from the configuration repository is deleted successfully.

ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application ivtApp is complete.

ADMA5106I: Application ivtApp uninstalled successfully.

ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application ivtApp is complete.

ADMA5069E: The installation of application ivtApp failed.  This application was in the middle of a full update and therefore is uninstalled from the configuration session.  Discard your current configuration session immediately to recover the application.  Do not save changes to the WebSphere Application Server configuration repository.  The application is not uninstalled from this repository.  Until the current configuration session is discarded you do not see this application in the current session.

WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminApp.update('ivtApp', 'app', '[-operation update -contents /tmp/ivtApp.ear  -usedefaultbindings -nodeployejb]')"; exception information:

com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7418E: Application update for ivtApp failed: see previous messages for details.
```

Comment: Looks like you might had 2 concurrent sessions with modifications on same user (eg. from web console and wsadmin scripting). Make sure you have current repo state (no unsaved changes) and no concurrent logins.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am the only one logging into the WAS console and the wsadmin scripting. Any other ideas?